# Can't successfully return a const char* I have created by calling c_str() on a string. (C++)

Tags: c++, string, scope, return, lifetime

I have a class in my program that has a member variable, an int called number, and a member function, getName(), that is MEANT to return the words "Dice: #" as a const char*, but with the # replaced by the number stored in the class.

```
const char* getName(){
 return "Dice:";
}
```

works perfectly well.

```
const char* getName(){
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << number;
 std::string s;
 s = "Dice: " + ss.str();
 return s.c_str();
}
```

does NOT work fine, and returns what seems to be garbage. I can't figure out the correct way to go about this. If I use cout to print `s.c_str()` it prints what I expect.

Comment: Take care of lifetime: A string-literal is immutable static storage, an automatic variable is scope-lifetime.

Comment: This is strange. Can you post the output of the getName() 'garbage'? It works okay for me.

EDIT: It's undefined behavior because the const char * scope does not extend past the local variable, and strings are stored in static read-only memory.

Comment: @TylerLewis: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: just return a std::string .. or a unique_ptr<char*> (but really, don't do the second thing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short and sweet answer is that you can't do this, the way you've set this up.

The `std::string` object from which you retrieve your `c_str()` is in the function's local scope. When the function returns that `std::string` object gets destroyed.

That

```
std::string s;
```

is a local function object. When the function returns it ceases to exist. It joins the choir invisible. It is no more. It's an ex-object.

And when a `std::string` object gets destroyed, any of its `c_str()`s are no longer valid. This is why you're getting garbage: undefined behavior.

There is no way to do this without changing the overall design of it, in some way. There are many ways to go forward. Some of the possibilities:

## Return a `std::string` in the first place

Just return the `std::string` from `getName()`. Whoever calls it can store this `std::string`, for a while, and grab it's `c_str()` if it needs it.

## Use a `std::string` with a different scope

If this `getName()` is a class method, you could have a private `std::string` class member, have `getName()` store the string there, and return its `c_str()`.

Because the original `std::string` continues to exist, the returned `c_str()` remains valid. Note that there are some pitfalls here. If the caller calls `getName()` again, the previously-returned `c_str()` will no longer be valid.

## Conclusion

Just get in the habit of using and working with `std::string`s in your C++ code. That's what they're for.

The name "c_str()" should be a clue. It gives you a string to be used with C code, if there's any C code lying around, in the near vicinity. It's a C string. Are you writing C code here? No, you're writing C++ code.

Unless you're writing C code, or are talking to a C library, there's no need to use `c_str`() in the first place. If you're writing C++ code, you should be using `std::string`s. If you need to call a C library function, call `c_str()` to pass the appropriate C library function parameter, and speak of this C string no more.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the thoroughness of this answer. I'm going to go through and modify my code to return a string in the first place and convert to c_str() only where necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a local variable 's' and then returning a pointer to the strig withing the string memory.

When the function returns the string goes out of scope (and so does the pointer)

Best bet is probally change getname to return a std::string, and then if you need to use the c_str, use it where it is returned.

```
std::string name = object.getName();
printf("name = %s", name.c_str());
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that since it's one of several inherited classes that all share this virtual function getName() so I'd have to run through my code and change all of them to return a string instead, but if this is the only way then I guess that's what I'll do!
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Yup ... basically, *"it ain't `const` ..."*